# Interpret error from testbench after sending in an XSLT processed document

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am wondering how to read and interpret below error line from a suppliers test bench. My understanding is that the supplier run default configuration.

My assumptions:

**<Q{.../2017-09-30}disposition-of-results>**

...is referring to a element with namespace.

The Q is for QName the date is for the namespace path and "disposition-of-results" is element name.

The error complaints about that content model does not allow 2 defined elements to come one after another?

```
Something wrong detected at line -1 of file Xxx. In content of element <xbrl>: The content model does not allow element <Q{.../2017-09-30}disposition-of-results> to appear immediately after element <Q{.../2017-09-30}Sales>. The following elements would be valid here: xbrli:unit, link:footnoteLink, xbrli:context, xbrli:tuple, xbrli:item (or nothing).
```

Comment: That is a validation error telling that your input or perhaps your output is not valid against a schema or DTD.

Comment: I did found the problem. When I run a query towards JSON data (it's produced map) the entry point of path is "disposition-of-results" and then system should go down one step in path to find correct name. This does not work due to wrong path expression and that's why it shows "disposition-of-result". So the mistake is mine. The reason for the question, though was to try to understand the structure of the error message, to shorten the leadtime of finding the error.